# How to remove specific letters using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

`var cartstring = "27,00 - R"`

How can I remove spaces and "-" and "R" using only regex (not allowed to use slice etc.)? I need to make strings cartstring1 and cartstring2 which should both be equal to "27,00", first by removing spaces and "-" and "R", and second by allowing only numbers and ",".

`cartstring1 = cartstring.replace(/\s/g, "");`
`cartstring2 = cartstring.replace(/\D/g, "");`

Please help me modify these regular expressions to have a working code. I tried to read about regex but still cannot quite get it. 
 Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Why not some kind of `cartstring.split(" ")[0]`?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar "27,00" on both

Comment: You could also remove any char except digits or a comma `[^\d,]+`https://regex101.com/r/OcQvSP/1

Comment: as The fourth bird said, use text.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, '')

Answer (score 2):

you can just capture just what you are interested in number and comma:

```js
let re = /[\d,]+/g
let result = "27,00 - R".match(re)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks all, that was very informative.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the characters you want to remove:

```js
var cartstring = "27,00 - R"
let res = cartstring.replace(/(\s|-|R)/g, "")
console.log(res)
```

Or alternatively, split the string by a space and get the first item:

```js
var cartstring = "27,00 - R"
let res = cartstring.split(" ")[0]
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 replacements, one replacing all whitespace chars `\s` and the other replacing all non digits `\D`, but note that `\D` also matches `\s` so you could omit the first call.

Using `\D` will also remove the comma that you want to keep, so you can match all chars except digits or a comma using `[^\d,]+` in a single replacement instead:

```js
var cartstring = "27,00 - R";
console.log(cartstring.replace(/[^\d,]+/g, ''));
```